# String resource with "%" symbol

Tags: android, resources

I am having String.xml and performing Localization.

while writing content in String tag I notice that appending text after second "%" symbol throws error.

```
<string name="result_unlikely">Improbable 20% to 50%</string>//working

<string name="result_unlikely">Improbable 20% to 50% required</string>//not working
```

any idea?

**Note**: I know i can write it runtime but as mentioned I am implementing Localization so using string.xml is far better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved.

By adding *formatted="false"* problem resolved.

```
<string name="result_unlikely" formatted="false">Improbable 20% to 50% required</string>
```